# How to change border radius of side bar image without changing other images?

Tags: html, css

I just placed an image in the 'about me' section of my main page and am not able to change the border radius of the image without all the other images changing as well..

**CSS:**

```
.well .col-lg-12 .about, img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="well">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <img class="about" src= "https://storage.googleapis.com/simply-sturgis-website-files/Untitled.jpg" style="width:230px"></img>
    <h3>Hello! I'm Jennifer.</h3>
    <p>I'm a part time marketing assistant, part time blogger, who loves food, beauty, and fashion. But what 23 year old doesn't?!</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/32nydcjw/)

This is the result of the code I currently have:

[image: This is the result]

Comment: Change the border radius of only the class of the image you want to change.

Comment: If the styling is unique to the one image, give it an `id` and style it accordingly.

Comment: The comma in your selector is the problem; it says to target all images. If you want that specific image, your selector should be `.well .col-lg-12 img.about`

Comment: Thanks @DrewKennedy! That worked!

Comment: @JenniferSturgis Don't attach CSS to your IDs. It's not good practice. Remember IDs are unique and can't be cascaded. Use a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things wrong that you should consider.

**DO NOT STYLE IDs** - IDs can't be cascaded and they are unique. This means if you wan to share your styles, you can't because you attached it to an ID instead of a class which you can reuse.

For example: You can't have two `DIVs` with ID `about`. But if you wanted both `DIVs` to act the same way, now you are going to have to repeat the CSS rule for both `DIVs`. Instead, you create a `myClass`, style it, and repeat the class wherever you want as much as you want. --- Scalability & Maintainability

**DO NOT STYLE BOOTSTRAP CLASSES** - Some Bootstrap classes, specially `col-*` classes, shouldn't be styled or considered in your specificity. This creates a problem because your style will only work for as long as you want it to be `col-lg-12`. If you decide to change the class to make it respond, your specificity failed. Instead cascade a custom class and use it as a hook of your specificity.

For example, You styled your specificity `.col-lg-3 .myClass{something}` But decided later that `col-lg-3` was too big. So you change it to `col-lg-2`. Now you have to go to the CSS and change that specificity to `.col-lg-2 .myClass{something}`...Double work. If you leave bootstrap class out of it, you only change the HTML architecture and nothing else

This is what I would do if I were you:

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 myClass">
    <img class="about" src= "https://storage.googleapis.com/simply-sturgis-website-files/Untitled.jpg" style="width:230px"></img>
    <h3>Hello! I'm Jennifer.</h3>
    <p>I'm a part time marketing assistant, part time blogger, who loves food, beauty, and fashion. But what 23 year old doesn't?!</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
```

And your CSS

```
.myClass img.about {
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/KVqvZp)

Comment: Thanks! How would you center it within the div?

Comment: Remember the custom class I recommended? do this: .myClass {text-align:center;}...Another reason why custom classes are import. You can use that class as a hook (parent class)) to handle all specificities within that element

Comment: Oh, and although is unrelated, You are using Bootstrap3 which is a great mobile first framework. instead of col-lg-12, do col-xs-12. Start with the mobile class and it already knows you want that same size all the way up. I changed that in the demo as well so you can see

Answer (score -1):

Give the image an id tag and just use that id in the CSS. This way, you only are targeting that specific image, and not the others:

https://jsfiddle.net/32nydcjw/

HTML:

```
 <!-- About Me Well -->
  <div class="well">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <img id="aboutMeImg" src= "https://storage.googleapis.com/simply-sturgis-website-files/Untitled.jpg" style="width:230px"></img>
        <h3>Hello! I'm Jennifer.</h3>
        <p>I'm a part time marketing assistant, part time blogger, who loves food, beauty, and fashion. But what 23 year old doesn't?!</p>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#aboutMeImg {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```